# Return a .href and .text from an element on a different webpage without loading that page

Tags: javascript, html

Use case:

Create a organization hierarchy on our page

Workflow:

I am attempting to create a script that captures a .href link on within `webpage1` utilizing the elements within the `webpage1`. Modify that url, to be able to go to the next users webpage `webpage2`. What I am unsure about is how to use the modified url `webpage2`, and run the same exact `document.querySelector()` and return the .href and .text from that `webpage2` to `webpage1`.

```
//this simply returns the elements <href> that I am looking for on the webpage
webpage1 = document.querySelector("#profile-header > div > div:nth-child(1) > header > div:nth-child(2) > div.layout-Flex-___Flex__display-flex___2z5mr.layout-Flex-___Flex__flex-direction-column___1-7rr.SpaceGap-___SpaceGap__container-col-tiny___3hDeu.SpaceGap-___SpaceGap__container-row-tiny___1P7MU > div:nth-child(2) > dl > dd:nth-child(6) > ul > li > span > a").href;
```

"https://xxxx.xxxx.com/people/6962ae84-5add-4ea4-9e00-f721db9def4b/show/general"

```
//this part takes that <href> link and modifies it to what I need the link to look like 
segments = weppage1.split("/"); segments[segments.length - 1] = "" + "teams-allocations/teams/"; webpage2 = segments.join("/")
```

"https://xxxx.xxxx.com/people/6962ae84-5add-4ea4-9e00-f721db9def4b/show/teams-allocations/teams/"

problem:

I do not know how to make a GET request to the same element in `webpage2` so I can return that .href and .text without navigating to that actual `webpage2`.

Comment: Did you try to fetch the webpage2 via fetch() function?
[Reference](https://javascript.info/fetch)

Comment: I have not used it before but from what I have read, "You can’t get a Document back directly from the Fetch API itself."

Comment: I think that this isn't impossible. Which language do you use in the server side?

Comment: OK, can you try this please: Open a Google Spreadsheet. Click a cell and write this formula:  `=IMPORTXML("https://your second link"; "//a/@href")` So that we can see if the page is fetchable or not.